# Creating an ETL system (Data import and transformation)

Tags: c#, transform

I have been tasked to write a module for importing data into a client's system. 
I thought to break the process into 4 parts:

**1.** Connect to the data source (SQL, Excel, Access, CSV, ActiveDirectory, Sharepoint and Oracle) - DONE
**2.** Get the available tables/data groups from the source - DONE
    i. Get the available fields form the selected table/data group - DONE
    ii. Get all data from the selected fields - DONE
**3.** Transform data to the user's requirements
**4.** Write the transformed data the the MSSQL target

I am trying to plan how to handle complex data transformations like:
Get column A from Table tblA, inner joined to column FA from table tblB, and concatenate these two with a semicolon in between.

OR

Get column C from table tblC on source where column tblC.D is not in table tblG column G on target database.

My worry is not the visual, but the representation in code of this operation.

I am NOT asking for sample code, but rather for some creative ideas.

The data transformation will not be with free text, but drag and drop objects that represent actions.

I am a bit lost, and need some fresh input.

Comment: Not quite sure what it is you are asking here. Do you want to know how to do the *"Get Field A from Table A, inner joined to Field FA from table B, and concatenate these two with a semicolon inbetween"* part, or was there something else?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how represent these different operations generically in code. Not asking for actual code, but rather for patterns or best practices where ETL is concerned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer: [Manipulate values in a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432614/manipulate-values-in-a-datatable/6579847#6579847)

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can grab some ideas from this open source project: [Rhino ETL](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/545.aspx).