# Paging through a datatable in codebehind

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to handle very large datatables (2 million rows+) that comes from databases (SQL, Oracle, Access, MySQL, Sharepoint etc) outside of my control: Currently I loop through every row and column building a string object, but I run [out of memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx) at about 100k rows.

The only solution I may take is to break the datatable into smaller pieces and persisting each block before starting on the next block of rows.

Since I cannot add ROW_NUMBER() or anything similar, I have to handle the populated datatable.

How can I easily (keep performance in mind) break the populated datatable into smaller datatables like paging?

PS there is no visual component to this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using string concatenation? like this `string += string`.

Change that to [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and you should not have problems, at least not for 20k rows.

Comment: I have marked yours as the correct answer, but in truth it was not the complete answer. I ended up breaking the incoming datatable into 500 row batches.

Comment: Tnx. It was just my knee-jerk reaction when someone mentions strings and performance :) I'm just curious, you did not ellaborate why you would want a string representation of 100k rows. Also, if you could show some code, we might be able to help further..

Comment: refer to this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388682/creating-an-etl-system-data-import-and-transformation for an overview of the (now complete) project. MySQL is just a new datasource being added

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about filling a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) object (which loads the results of your calls into memory before processing), you will likely be better off using a datareader for each of the mentioned providers so then you can process each row as it is read from the database instead of storing the DataTable in memory...

A [great answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676753/sqldataadapter-vs-sqldatareader/1676809#1676809) lists the pro/cons of datareaders/datatables

If you're already using datareaders- ignore this. But your memory problem might be from also storing the retrieved results...